# AWS CLI command to get the Image size of the AMI in table/text format

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, snapshot, amazon-ami, image-size

I am running this AWS CLI command to get a list of AMI IDs along with their ImageSize but I am unable to list the ImageSize and display it as a separate column.

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owners self --region us-east-1 --profile prod 
--query 'Images[*].[Name,ImageId,VolumeSize,Description,ImageLocation,OwnerId,Public,State,CreationDate,Platform,RootDeviceType,VirtualizationType,Tags[?Key==`System`]|[0].Value,Tags[?Key==`SubSystem`]|[0].Value,BlockDeviceMappings[]|[].Ebs.VolumeSize]' 
--output text
```

Can anybody please help me here?so that I can have these sections in my table as shown in the mysampletable picture:

[mysampletable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PC7P.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html) the `aws ec2 describe-images` CLI command doesn't return an `ImageSize`. However, it returns `BlockDeviceMappings[*].Ebs.VolumeSize`, which you already retrieve as part of your query.